# Elasticsearch aggregation over children document field values

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm facing the following problem of selecting and sorting parent documents based on an aggregated value over its children documents. The aggregation (e.g. sum) itself depends on a query string, i.e. which children documents are relevant for the aggregation.

Example: Given the documents **basket A** and **basket B**, for each `basket document`, I am looking to sum over the  `number` field of its `fruit` children if the  `name` field matches my query, e.g. `apples`.

```
PUT /baskets/_doc/0
{
  "name": "basket A", 
  "fruit": [
    {
      "name": "apples",
      "number": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "oranges",
      "number": 3
    }
  ]
}

PUT /baskets/_doc/1
{
  "name": "basket B",
  "fruit": [
    {
      "name": "apples",
      "number": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "apples",
      "number": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Mappings:

```
PUT /baskets
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": { "type": "text" },
      "fruit": { 
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": { "type": "text" },
          "number": { "type": "long" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- Use case 1: Which basket has (strictly) more than 5 apples? Would expect only **basket B**
- Use case 2: Sort baskets by number of apples. Would expect **basket B** with a total of 6 apples, then **basket A** with a total of 2 apples.

How can one implement this using the Elasticsearch (7.8.0) query DSL?

I have tried so far with [nested queries and aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) without success.

Thanks!

*Edit: Added mappings*

*Edit: Updated the numbers to better reflect the problem*

*Edit: Added possible answer to **Use case 2** (see comments to the answer from @joe):

```
GET /profiles/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "aggs_baskets": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "order": {"nest > fruit_filter > fruit_sum": "desc"}
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nest":{
          "nested":{
            "path": "fruit"
          },
          "aggs":{
            "fruit_filter":{
              "filter": {
                "term": {"fruit.name": "apple"}
              },
              "aggs":{
                "fruit_sum":{
                  "sum": {"field": "fruit.number"}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your mappings (or the generated mappings), you can definitely do that with nested queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of searching and testing, here are (in addition to @joe's answer to **use case 2**) possible queries for both use cases. Note that both use cases require to change the mapping for the field `name` to be of type `keyword`.

**Use case 1**: Which basket has (strictly) more than 5 apples? Would expect only **basket B**

For more information on filtering results by their aggregation value see [Bucket Selectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)

```
GET /baskets/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "aggs_baskets": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nest":{
          "nested":{
            "path": "fruit"
          },
          "aggs":{
            "fruit_filter":{
              "filter": {
                "match": {"fruit.name": "apples"}
              },
              "aggs":{
                "fruit_sum":{
                  "sum": {"field": "fruit.number"}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "basket_sum_filter":{
          "bucket_selector":{
            "buckets_path":{
              "fruitSum":"nest > fruit_filter > fruit_sum"
            },
            "script":"params.fruitSum > 5"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... yielding

```
...,

"buckets": [
    {
        "key": "basket B",
        "doc_count": 1,
        "nest": {
            "doc_count": 2,
            "fruit_filter": {
                "doc_count": 2,
                "fruit_sum": {
                    "value": 6
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**Use case 2**: Sort baskets by number of apples. Would expect **basket B** with a total of 6 apples, then **basket A** with a total of 2 apples.

```
GET /baskets/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "aggs_baskets": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "order": {"nest > fruit_filter > fruit_sum": "desc"}
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nest":{
          "nested":{
            "path": "fruit"
          },
          "aggs":{
            "fruit_filter":{
              "filter": {
                "term": {"fruit.name": "apple"}
              },
              "aggs":{
                "fruit_sum":{
                  "sum": {"field": "fruit.number"}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... yielding

```
...,

"buckets": [
    {
        "key": "basket B",
        "doc_count": 1,
        "nest": {
            "doc_count": 2,
            "fruit_filter": {
                "doc_count": 2,
                "fruit_sum": {
                    "value": 6
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "basket A",
        "doc_count": 1,
        "nest": {
            "doc_count": 2,
            "fruit_filter": {
                "doc_count": 1,
                "fruit_sum": {
                    "value": 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use case 1:

```
GET baskets/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "fruit",
      "inner_hits": {}, 
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "fruit.name": {
                  "value": "apples"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "fruit.number": {
                  "gte": 5
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Strictly more than 5 --> `gt`; >=5 --> `gte`.

Also notice the `inner_hits` part -- this gives you the actual nested subdocument which caused this particular basket to match the query. It's not required but good-to-know.

#### Use case 2:

```
GET baskets/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "fruit.number": {
        "nested_path": "fruit",
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Use case 2 Edit:

There are probably cleaner ways of doing this but I'd go with the following:

```
GET baskets/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "multiply_and_add": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "params": {
          "only_fruit_name": "apples"
        },
        "init_script": "state.by_basket_name = [:]",
        "map_script": """
          def basket_name = params._source['name'];
          def fruits = params._source['fruit'].findAll(group -> group.name == params.only_fruit_name);
          
          for (def fruit_group : fruits) {
            def number = fruit_group.number;
            
            if (state.by_basket_name.containsKey(basket_name)) {
              state.by_basket_name[basket_name] += number;
            } else {
              state.by_basket_name[basket_name] = number;
            }
          }
        """,
        "combine_script": "return state.by_basket_name",
        "reduce_script": "return states"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding a hash map along the lines of

```
{
  ...
  "aggregations":{
    "multiply_and_add":{
      "value":[
        {
          "basket A":2,
          "basket B":6
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Sorting can either be done in the `reduce_script` or within your ES response post-processing pipeline. You could of course choose to go w/ (sorted) lists and [lambdas](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/7.8/painless-lambdas.html)...

Notice the required `nested_path`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I updated the numbers in my question to make it more clear: Unfortunately, for both use cases, the number depends on the aggregation over its sub-documents. E.g.when filtering the bucket for > 5 apples, the query has to aggregate over all sub-documents

Comment: The updated answer solves **use case 2**. After several hours I've found an alternative that seems a little

Comment: ... leaner. I've updated my question with the answer to **use case 2**.

Comment: It does! The "answer" can be found in the "aggregations" > "aggs_baskets" > "buckets" key, which in this case holds a list of "basket A", "basket B", ... sorted by their number of apples along with the exact count.